# What else could be the cause of this Dell Inspiron 1526 not showing the BIOS

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, dell-inspiron, maintenance

My dad just gave me his old inspiron 1526, which does not show the bios when booting (see image below of what I should have)

[image]

I have a black screen at start, without any HD booting noise and of course, no bios.

I thought ,after checking the net, that the issue might be due to the CMOS battery, that needed replacement. I changed it and yet, I have the same black screen.

What other part of the laptop should I check?

- RAM?
- HD that needed to be replaced?
- Else?

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions

Update: I found the Leds are lighting up and I can hear the CPU fan. I've checked some of the dell forums and I found the autodiagnostic function (`fn`+`Power On`).

When running it, I have the `9` and the `A`, running very fast and simustaneously... (a bit like in the image below)

[image]

Comment: What OS is installed?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified whether you get power LED to light up and CPU fan to spin up? The answer below assumes that you have a known working power adapter, and that you tried turning the laptop on without the laptop battery inserted.

If the system powers up but you have no beep codes then it could be a dead mainboard or a dead CPU, but since the CPU is usually soldered that is really equivalent to a dead mainboard.

If you have experience with Dell laptop teardown you could try disconnecting HDD and optical drive, and removing the RAM stick(s) (provided that RAM is not soldered) to see if you will get it to POST with beep codes.

It could also be a problem with voltage regulation on the mainboard, but checking that requires a bit more skill.

Another thing to check would be LCD screen backlight and cable/connector.

Finally, it is possible that the BIOS is corrupted. Desoldering flash chip and programming it using EEPROM programmer can fix that provided that you know how to extract .ROM file from Dell BIOS update Windows executable.

If the laptop is valuable to you, my suggestion would be to seek someone who is experienced with laptop electronics repairs and who can try to diagnose and fix the problem.

**Update 1:**
If you can manage to run ePSA, then you can check the resulting error code [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/yu/en/yubsdt1/product-support/product/inspiron-1526/diagnose) (click on Error code lookup tab).

**Update 2:**
You can find owner's and service manuals for that laptop [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-1526/manuals). In the Owner's Manual, diagnostics is described starting at page 98.

Comment: Hi @igor-levicki, many thanks for your answer. Leds are lighting up and I can hear the CPU fan. I've checked some of the dell forums and I found the autodiagnostic function (`fn`+`Power On`). 

When running it, I have the `9` and the `A`, running very fast and simustaneously... (a bit like in this image) http://i.stack.imgur.com/loKk9.gif

Comment: Do you have any sort of error code?

Comment: what kind of errors code do you mean?

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: I'm not even here ... guess I will need to ask my dad to go back for a pc checkup

Comment: I have updated the answer to add details about diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

Blinking 9 and A flash code: 2 possibilities, without third one (down arrow)lit and with 3rd one lit.

[image]

The video card is preventing the system from completing POST.

Possible solutions:

1. Replacing the video card.
2. Replacing the system board.

[image]

The keyboard is preventing the system from completing POST.

1. Reseating the keyboard cable.
2. Replacing the keyboard.
3. Replacing the system board.

[Source](http://www.bay-wolf.com/portpostcodes.htm)

Comment: Hi @moab, it is the `9` and the `A`, simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

### Check the CMOS battery.

One day when I turned on the laptop, it showed a black screen and the Caps Lock and Scroll Lock LEDs were flashing. I researched it and found a forum in which one user said this was an issue with the CMOS battery, and sure it was, i replaced it and it went back to normal.

To replace the CMOS battery I had to disassemble every part of the laptop. It is a tedious task, but it gets the job done.

I double checked by using a multimeter to test the battery's voltage and it was dry indeed.